# error: call to undeclared function 'ffi_prep_closure'; I [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: ruby

I am using

```
rvm install ruby-2.7.1
```

to install ruby for mac M1 but the above error appears and the installation process has stopped, how can I fix the error, please help me, thank you everyone

```
closure.c:264:14: error: call to undeclared function 'ffi_prep_closure'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    result = ffi_prep_closure(pcl, cif, callback, (void *)self);
```

i have tried many existing and obvious ways when searching above but it doesn't work

Comment: please check https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1699

Answer (score 1):

Try ignoring deprecated syntax via

```
CPPFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC rvm install 2.7.1
```

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work, the  __rvm_make -j8 error still appears. error message: 
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:942:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RSA_SSLV23_PADDING'
    DefRSAConst(SSLV23_PADDING);
    ^
ossl_pkey_rsa.c:877:58: note: expanded from macro 'DefRSAConst'
#define DefRSAConst(x) rb_define_const(cRSA, #x, INT2NUM(RSA_##x))

Comment: try

brew install openssl@1.1

ruby-install ruby-2.7.1 -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)